# Javascript more than one RegEx backreferance

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible for javascript to to create multiple new variables using RegEx back references?
Something like:

```
var temp = fileName.replace(new RegExp( "(^.)(.*)(_.*)(-.*)", "i" ),"\$1\$2\$3\$4");
var first = $1;
var forth = $4;
```

In perl I would do something like this:

```
$uprate =~ /(^.)(.*)(_.*)(-.*)/$1 $2 $3 $4/;

$first = $1;
$forth = $4;
```

Comment: Those are not back refs, they're just memory captures. Just remove the backslash should make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do you access the matched groups in a javascript regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Javascript String's `match` method.  It will return an object containing all matched groups.

```
var matches = fileName.match(/(^.)(.*)(_.*)(-.*)/i);
var first = matches[1];
var fourth = matches[4];
```

The match method will return `null` if the string doesn't match the regex, so be sure to test for that unless you're certain it will succeed.

Comment: Thanks cspotcode, clearly I was pursuing the wrong path with what I was using. Your solution worked perfectly.